# Python forecast function of stats.VAR not working

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data set of macroeconomic variables. And I'm using stats.VAR for model fit and forecast.  My data set, df, is normalized by column already:

```
def main():
    cwd = os.getcwd()
    old = os.path.join(cwd, 'dat','prod_lf_usuk_520.xlsx')
    new=old.replace('\\','/')    
    myList = ['UK','US']  
    for idx, region in enumerate(myList):
        df = pd.read_excel(open(new,'rb'), sheetname = region)
        df = (df - np.mean(df, axis=0))/np.std(df, axis = 0)
        model = stats.VAR(df)
        model.select_order(15)     
        results = model.fit(maxlags=15, ic='aic')
        results.summary()
        lag_order = results.k_ar
        steps_to_forecast = 1
        results.forecast(df[-lag_order:], steps_to_forecast)
```

Everything works till the results.forecast line.  I keep getting the *** KeyError: -1 or *** KeyError: -2 error, no matter what lag_order and steps_to_forecast values I set.  In other words, results.forecast(df[-1],1]) or results.forecast(df[-4],1) or results.forecast(df[-3],2) got the same error.

I'm a newbie on Python and couldn't figure out a solution.  Can someone experienced with stats.VAR shed me some lights please?

Thanks much in advance!

Comment: This seems to be the only relevant part of the code: `df[-lag_order:]`, but we don't know what `df` is or what `lag_order` is.

Comment: Thanks, Zvone, for your kind reply.  The lag_order results.k_ar gives back is 4.  But I tried the lag_order from 1 to 5, and steps_for_forecast from 1 to 5, the key error of -1 or -2 remains.  My df is the normalized set of macroecon variables.  It is a 483x6 matrix.  I don't mind posting the data file here, only I don't know how.  Thanks again.

Comment: if `df` is really a `set`, then you cannot do `df[index:]`. If it is a `dict`, you still cannot do that. If it is a `list`, then you can, if it is a valid index. So, you should post minimal code which shows at least: the type of `df`, the value of `lag_order` and the full traceback. Otherwise it is not possible to know what happened.

Comment: Hi, zvone, thanks for coming back.  My code is actually really simple and I just edited my original post, which shows the full code now.  I used dataframe for df, and as I said, every line of the code works till the last .  I don't know how to get around the KeyError of -1 and -2.

Comment: I don't use [tag:pandas], but based on [read_excel doc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) and [DataFrame doc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#dataframe), I don't see why `df[-lag_order:]` would ever be valid. `df` is *"DataFrame or Dict of DataFrames"* and neither of them seems to support this.

Comment: Hi, zvone, df[-lag_order:] should work.  For if I do test = df[-3:], I got valid last 3 rows back from df.  But let me try other types.  If a different type works well, I will update you here.  Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

I also encountered the same problem. The solution is to use:

```
df.values[-k:]
```

By `k` I meant the Order p of AR you used while training the VAR model. So let's say, suppose you have a training set and a test set data. The `-k` in this will be the number of k rows in the training set from the end, after which the test set begins.

Comment: I'm afraid this is not very helpful - what is `k`? There is no `k` variable in the code in the question.

Comment: By k I meant the Order p of AR you used while training the VAR model.  So let's say, suppose you have a training set and a test set data. The `-k`  in this will be the number of k rows in the training set from the end, after which the test set begins.

Comment: Can you please edit your answer and add this information? Without it your answer is not very useful. Thanks.